# Mobile content witdh(body) = media width, but user can still scroll

Tags: android, iphone, viewport, meta, device-width

I overlooked all the web ( i guess) and tried to find the solution for this task:
I have all requirements to show a correct content on  mobile(I mean meta media and css media and so on), but on my android phone I can scroll to the right. I checked if there are no divs with width more than 320px. Website I'm talking about is http://vasiliib.p.ht/leverage/

I tought this is cause my page content and created a separate page http://vasiliib.p.ht/leverage/mobile.html. Here I inserted simple html code. And, there is the same problem..

I am frustrated .. Please clean my eyes..and show me my mistake, please..

looking forward for your reply.
regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

This is the correct answer. It works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

```
body{
 margin:0px;
}
```

should read:

```
body{
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

Where are you handling you're responsive design stuff?

Also this:

```
.bg-course-content-02 {
    background-image: url("http://vasiliib.p.ht/leverage/files/css/../img/bg-course-content-02.png");
    margin-left: -970px;
    width: 923px;
    height: 555px;
}
```

This:

```
.bg-course-content-04 {
    background-image: url("http://vasiliib.p.ht/leverage/files/css/../img/bg-course-content-04.png");
    margin-left: -970px;
    width: 923px;
    height: 555px;
}
```

and this:

```
.bg-course-content-06 {
    background-image: url("http://vasiliib.p.ht/leverage/files/css/../img/bg-course-content-06.png");
    margin-left: -970px;
    width: 923px;
    height: 555px;
}
```

check your widths..

Comment: May be I have some issues with those blocks, but what you'll  say about this page: http://vasiliib.p.ht/leverage/mobile.html . It's the same problem....:( And content is minimalistic...

Comment: css file for mobile layout only is ./files/css/mobile.css

Answer (score -1):

Have you included the meta tag inside the head tag of the HTML?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-witdh, initial-scale=1">
```

that meta tag set the width of the page to the width of your device.